# Правильно выводить id

Tags: java, классы

вопрос заключается в следующем, есть два класса, один "Пользователь", а второй "Сообщения", вопрос в том, как реализовать чтобы при добавлении пользователя за ним закреплялся постоянный id(минимум возможный id был бы 1) и при добавлении нового пользователя id увеличивался на 1! Немного трудности с этим, должен ли быть id записан в конструкторе класса "Пользователь" и как это реализовать чтобы он оставался постоянный за одним пользователем? П.С. класс "Сообщения" нужен для того, чтобы за определенным пользователем сохранялись сообщения.

Answer (score 2):

Например, так :

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class User {

    private static long ID = 1;

    private final long id;

    private final List<Message> messages;

    public User() {
        this.id = ID++;
        this.messages = new ArrayList<>();        
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public List<Message> getMessages() {
        return messages;
    }

    public User addMessage(String text) {
        messages.add(new Message(text, this));
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" + "id=" + id + ", messages=" + messages + '}';
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        User user1 = new User()
                .addMessage("Test1")
                .addMessage("Test2");
        User user2 = new User()
                .addMessage("Test3");

        System.out.println(user1);
        System.out.println(user2);

    }

}

class Message{

    private static long ID = 1;

    private final long id;

    private final LocalDateTime dateTime;

    private final String text;

    private final User author;

    public Message(String text, User user) {
        this.id = ID++;
        this.dateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        this.text = text;
        this.author = user;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getDateTime() {
        return dateTime;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public User getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Message{" + "id=" + id + ", dateTime=" + dateTime + ", text=" + text + '}';
    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо. А как сделать тогда чтобы это айди закреплялось за сообщениями в другом классе?

Comment: Когда final дописываю в переменную, то компил. ругается

Comment: @Str компилятор ругается на финальную переменную, если она не инициализирована при создании объекта, т.е. вы добавили конструктор без ее инициализации. может я не совсем понял вашу проблему. но код дополнил, а там разбирайтесь и задавайте вопросы

Answer (score 0):

Я использовал следующий код для генерации уникального идентификатора (как строкового так и целого):

```
public final class UUID {
    transient private static Random random=new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    transient private static AtomicInteger stringCounter =new AtomicInteger(0);
    transient private static AtomicLong idCounter=new AtomicLong(0);

    public static synchronized String getStringId() {
        StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
        sb.append(System.currentTimeMillis()).append('.').append(random.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE)).append('.').append(stringCounter.addAndGet(1));
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static long getLongId() {
        return idCounter.addAndGet(1);
    }
}
```

Обращаю внимание на Thread safety - иногда это важно. В случае генерации целочисленного идентификатора используется `Atomic`

Вызывать можно откуда угодно. В вашем случае очевидно в конструкторе `User/Message`